# Dragging new events in Internet Explorer 10 are positioned incorrectly

Tags: fullcalendar, internet-explorer-10

Using FullCalendar and Internet Explorer 10, when dragging an event in Agenda Week View, the event is not positioned correctly on the y axis. This only happens when the page has a scroll to it.

For example, using the official demo (http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/selectable.html) drag an event with IE10 maximized. It should work like normal. Then resize the window so there is a scroll. Push the scroll all the way to the top and drag an event. It should work. Now scroll down a little bit on the page and drag an event. The start time will not line up with the mouse click.

I haven't been able to find anyone reporting this problem yet, but has anyone worked with and/or found a resolution?

**EDIT:** This also affects dragging existing events.

Comment: Using IE10 RTM at the moment. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the problem you described. Drag-drop is working smoothly with and without resizing/scrollbar. Would you give it another try with IE-RTM?

Comment: I have tested again the scenario you reported. The click-drag-drop works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done extensive testing with this since I first posted the question. I can confirm that, in Internet Explorer 10, the problem is no longer prevalent.

I assumed some Windows Update made fixes to IE10 since I first reported the issue. Therefore, I installed a fresh copy of Windows 8 in a Virtual Box, allowing it to perform no Windows Updates and the problem exists!

Looks like this was a bug in the IE10 engine that has been since resolved by Microsoft.